# How to convert a Scheme function that returns a closure to an equivalent Common Lisp function?

Tags: scheme, common-lisp

I am converting some Scheme code to Common Lisp. I don't know Scheme. I know a bit of Common Lisp.

I think that I understand this Scheme code:

```
(define (make-cell)
    (let ((local-name '()))
       (define (local-add-name name)
           (set! local-name name))
        (define (me message)
            (cond ((eq? message 'add-name) local-add-name)
                  ((eq? message 'name) local-name)))
     me))
```

Using that function, I can make two cells:

```
(define a (make-cell))
(define b (make-cell))
```

Then I can store a name inside each cell:

```
((a 'add-name) 'a)
((b 'add-name) 'b)
```

Then I can retrieve the name stored inside each cell:

```
(a 'name)
```

=> a

```
(b 'name)
```

=> b

The a-cell has stored inside it the name "a". The b-cell has stored inside it the name "b". I can query the a-cell for its name and it returns "a". I can query the b-cell for its name and it returns "b".

Am I understanding correctly thus far?

Now I would like to achieve the same functionality using Common Lisp. Here's the make-cell function that I created:

```
(defun make-cell ()
    (let ((local-name nil))
        (defun local-add-name (name)
            (setf local-name name))
        (defun me (message)
            (cond ((eq message 'add-name) #'local-add-name)
                  ((eq message 'name) local-name)))))
```

Apparently that is wrong, since it doesn't give the desired behavior, as I show next.

I make an a-cell and b-cell:

```
(setf a (make-cell))
(setf b (make-cell))
```

I store a name inside each cell:

```
(funcall (funcall a 'add-name) 'a)
(funcall (funcall b 'add-name) 'b)
```

When I retrieve the names, both cells return the same name:

```
(funcall a 'name)
```

=> b

```
(funcall b 'name)
```

=> b

Ouch!

Why do both cells return the same name? What am I doing wrong? How do I get the CL code to behave the same way as the Scheme code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Common Lisp does not have internal `define` like Scheme does (which is, by the way, syntactic sugar for `letrec` or `letrec*`<sup>†</sup>). The Common Lisp equivalent of `letrec` is `labels`, so you can use this:

```
(defun make-cell ()
  (let (local-name)
    (labels ((local-add-name (name)
               (setf local-name name))
             (me (message)
               (ecase message
                 (add-name #'local-add-name)
                 (name local-name))))
      #'me)))
```

This works as you'd expect (as tested on SBCL):

```
* (defvar *foo* (make-cell))

*FOO*
* (defvar *bar* (make-cell))

*BAR*
* (funcall (funcall *foo* 'add-name) "foo")

"foo"
* (funcall (funcall *bar* 'add-name) "bar")

"bar"
* (funcall *foo* 'name)

"foo"
* (funcall *bar* 'name)

"bar"
```

---

† Here's the `letrec` version of your code:

```
(define (make-cell)
  (let ((local-name #f))
    (letrec ((local-add-name (lambda (name)
                               (set! local-name name)))
             (me (lambda (message)
                   (case message
                     ((add-name) local-add-name)
                     ((name) local-name)))))
      me)))
```

or even:

```
(define (make-cell)
  (letrec ((local-name #f)
           (local-add-name (lambda (name)
                             (set! local-name name)))
           (me (lambda (message)
                 (case message
                   ((add-name) local-add-name)
                   ((name) local-name)))))
    me))
```

Answer (score 5):

Chris Jester-Young already gave a good answer, but alternatively you could restructure your function a little bit. Notice that neither of the functions call `ME` by name; you could just replace that with a `LAMBDA`:

```
(defun make-cell ()
  (let (local-name)
    (flet ((add-name (name) (setf local-name name)))
      (lambda (message)
        (ecase message
          ;; ADD-NAME is only used here, so you could make it a lambda too.
          (add-name #'add-name) 
          (name local-name))))))
```

If you later need to be able to refer to `ME` by name, [Alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/) provides a macro `NAMED-LAMBDA` that should work.

Of course, this looks suspiciously like implementing objects with closures. Since Common Lisp is a multi-paradigm language, it would be better to just use CLOS here:

```
(defclass cell ()
  ((local-name :initform "" :initarg :name :reader name :writer add-name)))

(let ((cell (make-instance 'cell)))
  (format t "~&Name: ~a~%Add name: ~a~%Name: ~a~%"
          (name cell)
          (add-name "foo" cell)
          (name cell)))
; Name: 
; Add name: foo
; Name: foo
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jkiiski!

Answer (score 3):

The other answers give the correct solution to your problem, here I will try to explain *why* your solution does not produce the intended result.

In Common Lisp there is the distinction between the *global environment* and the *lexical environments*.

The global environment (see the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_aa.htm)) is usually modified evaluating top-level forms, like `defvar`,  `defun`, `defmacro`, etc., for instance in REPL, and contains  bindings that have an indefinite extent and scope.

A lexical environment instead is an environment that contains information valid in a certain form (i.e. it is a “local” environment), so that in each point of a program we can talk about of the *current lexical environment*. It is typically modified by bindings of function parameters or local definitions, like `let`.

Just for completness: this two kinds of environment are also similar to those available in other languages, but in Common Lisp there is another special kind of environment, the [dynamic environment](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_aab.htm), which however is not of interest in this case.

So, while `defun` is usually found at top-level, you can give it inside the some other form, but, *in any case*, it:

> Defines a new function named function-name in the **global environment**. ... Evaluating defun causes function-name to be a global name for the function specified by the lambda expression ... processed in the **lexical environment** in which defun was executed.

(emphasis is mine). See the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defun.htm#defun).

In other words, *both* the functions that you have defined share the *same* variable 
`local-name`. The situation is more clear if you think that a `(defun ...)` form
internal to a function definition can be “moved” to the top level, by moving together with it the definition related to the variables free in it. And since neither `make-cell` makes explicit use of the variables, you can transform your original definition in the following equivalent one:

```
(let (local-name)
  (defun local-add-name (name)
    (setf local-name name))
  (defun me (message)
     (cond ((eq message 'add-name) #'local-add-name)
           ((eq message 'name) local-name)))
  (defun make-cell ()
    #'me))
```

This definition should make clear that the functions share exactly the *same* variable `local-name`. And note that this kind of construct, called [“let over lambda”](http://letoverlambda.com/textmode.cl/guest/toc) can be very useful if, for instance, you have to share a value between two functions, like in:

```
(let ((id 0))
  (defun get-new-id ()
    (incf id))
  (defun reset-id ()
    (setf id 0)))

(get-new-id) ; => 1

(get-new-id) ; => 2

(reset-id)   ; => 0

(get-new-id) ; => 1
```

On the other hand, the `label` and `flet` special operators modifies the current lexical environment, and are “executed” each time the enclosing function is called. So, each time the `make-cell` function is called, a *new* lexical environment is generated containing the *new* variable `local-name`, and the two *local* functions that refer to that variable, and the value returned is the *closure* of the second function over the new variable.

Comment: IMHO 'DEFUNS' inside other constructs is a code smell. DEFUN really is supposed to be a top-level function. Common Lisp is not 'secretly Scheme with bad syntax' (Kent Pitman). ;-)

Comment: @RainerJoswig, I agree that it can confuse people. But then, how one could code the last example without DEFUN? I can imagine only complex, not so elegant solutions.

Comment: Renzo: I would not use that at all. For example by embedding them in a LET, it prevents a compiler to recognize these functions as global functions at compile-time. I would just make \*%ID\* an unexported global variable.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: ok, but even if unexported, such variable could be visible to the package, defying the idea of “hidden state”. Certainly you could define a package only for the two functions, but it would be no so convenient. Ok, let’s say that IMHO one could tolerate such form of DEFUN, seeing it as an abbreviation to define a sort of “mini-package”, just for convenience (and I love the idea that Common Lisp was designed with lot of “conveniency” features :)

Comment: True, but I don't believe in that thing. My impression is that Lisp is more maintainable, when things are named objects (-> top-level symbols) with documentation, etc.  and when more complex things are self-identifying objects (-> CLOS). I want to look into an IDE and see it, find it, inspect it. anonymous closures are nice in theory, but for practical maintenance other features are more valuable than closures with little information.